# schedule events to take place after a event has taken place in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 app where I have customers who will download a clip and then there is a rating option right alongside it. I want to send a reminder email to them saying they have not rated after 1 day of downloading the video. How do I schedule this? I looked out the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem but I am not sure how to initiate a action after a download event takes place, it looks as if it is designed for events that take place continuously and repeatedly.

---

Also please note that the mail is to be sent only if the user has not rated. I am sure we can use whenever to send a mail 24 hours after the user has downloaded the video, but I need to check if the user has rated or not and then send this. How do I do that?

Comment: Can't you check if the user has rated or not in the cron job? or is it not captured at all?

Comment: I can find if the user has rated or not. I am not sure how to check that when I write a cron job or schedule it using whenever.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically, you can call ruby method from cron job. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be exactly after 24 hours? If not,

when the user downloads the clip, you can capture the download timestamp in your database against the user and have a nightly cron job(using whenever gem) send email to the users by checking the downloaded_at timestamp.

In `config/schedule.rb`

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do 
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end
```

In your class(Whatever you see below is pseudo code)

```
class MyModel
  def task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning
    if user_downloaded_before_24_hours and user_has_not_rated
      send_email
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this will work. Will accept after I try and it works. Thanks for your time, appreciate it!